# How can i access three vlans on one port?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, switching, trunk

I have **VLAN 11,12,13**. i need to use these vlans to L2 switch port( call it as port 3).

11 for printer, 12 for PC(dhcp from server), 30 for cisco phone.

Connected as from port to Cisco IP Phone, then to 8 port switch(non configurable), from 8 port switch to PC and Printer, how can i configure the port 3?

Am using cisco 2960 as L2 switch

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It's not clear which host is connected to which switch and how the swtiches are connected to each other.

Comment: @Peter Please refer the figure...

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think its possible to configure the phone's second port as trunk port. You can configure a separate voice VLAN for the phone, but the phone's access port will be an access port.

Apart from that, even if it was possible, how do you want to achieve VLAN configuration on an unmanaged switch? You want to separate the VLANs 11 and 12, which indicates you need the VLAN information in the packet header. As the unmanaged switch is not VLAN-aware, it won't remove the VLAN information and send the tagged frames to the host and printer connected to the switch. And I'd guess thats not true for all unmanaged switches, some of them may just drop VLAN tagged packets.

All in all I'd strongly suggest to rethink your network design. To help you further this direction, we need more information about the circumstances. Why not connect the phone and printer directly to the managed switch?

Comment: Before i use this setup by using L2 as SG300 switch, In that vlan 13 is Untagged and vlan 11 and 12 are tagged.    am out of ports in office :(

Comment: Hm... in this case I'd suggest to buy a (cheap) managed switch and configure an 802.1q trunk to the uplink switch, sending all VLANs to the office. Then you can connect the devices to those switches

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will be possible. PC Port on Phone is an access port and you can't change it to trunk port. Why don't you connect PC directly to Phone and then phone to 8 port switch. One trunk to 8-port switch from data switch and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If the 8 Port switch is an unmanaged switch it doesn't add VLAN headers which identivy at wich mac address table the Managed switch look and forward.
You can only have at least 2 VLANs in this topology. 
One nativ and one Voice VLAN if your managed swtich provides the voice vlan option:
config:
switch#(config):int fa0/3 
switch#(config-if):switchport mode trunk
switch#(config-if):switchport trunk nativ vlan **x**
switch#(config-if):switchport voice vlan **x**

Comment: Sorry, that is definitely wrong. The native VLAN needs to match on the specific trunk port only. On other trunk ports in your network, you can choose whatever native VLAN you like. Native only means that the packet is sent untagged. It needs to match on both sides such that the receiving switch knows what VLAN the untagged packet belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the phone as a swtich. I don't know if the phone can do that. If you would add a switch (say named 'fred') where the phone is, and plug the phone into that switch, yout would have to configure trunking between 'fred' and 'Data Port 3' and you'd have to configure trunking between 'fred' and the 8-Port switch (which, as Pompi said, is not possible, because it is unmanaged).

By the way, if you want those vlans to talk to each other, you'd need some kind of routing functionality, like a L3 switch or a router.

Comment: A VoIP phone _is_ a switch, and it negotiates a trunk with the switch, for the VoIP and data VLANs, but it will not trunk on the other port toward the PC.